# How can (re-)enable VS2008 Pro to debug javascript in IE8?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, debugging, internet-explorer-8

Since I installed IE8 (Win XP) Visual Studio 2008 Pro stopped deebugging javascript.
When I set a breakpoint on a line javasscript code and start debugging , I doesn't get hit anymore. This worked well when I had IE7 installed. The code hasn't changed. There were no other system changes performed at the same time.

How can I solve this problem (permanently if possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Internet Explorer, go to:

Tools (Menu) -> Internet Options -> Advanced (Tab)

Under the Browsing Section uncheck both:

'Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer)'

and

'Disable Script Debugging (Other)'

Comment: I'll recheck it when i get home in a few hours... and I'll get back to you with the results.

Comment: You were right I thought this upgrade would keep the preferences of ie7

Answer (score 0):

Now whit ie 8 you can debug javascript directly in dev tools bar. Open dev tools bar, go to tab script and click button start debugging. On the rigth pane you got other tab to get watch, breakpoints and other fonctionnality.